# Call suspend function in non suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin

When using Kotlin in Android app implemention, I met this problem.
I must overwrite a function which is in the aar, so I can not change the it. It is a non suspend function.

```
// from the aar
class A{
    fun doSomething()
}
```

But I have to overwrite this function and call suspend function. like this

```
class B() : A{
    overwrite fun doSomething(){
        // **I want to call a suspend function here**
    }
}
```

I am a new guy in Kotlin. As I know, I can use *runBlocking* to let it work.
Is there any other ideas on this?

Btw I also want to ask what is the Cons of the coroutines?

- Kotlin document said it will save the memory. We can create it as many as we can.

What is the difference of Kotlin corountines with others (C++, Go)?

using runBlock in my codes

Comment: Your follow-up question asking to compare coroutines in general between Kotlin and other languages is too broad to be on-topic for a StackOverflow question. It might be appropriate if you list specific characteristics about coroutines that you're confused about and want to compare to what's in one of those languages. But that should be a separate question from this one.

Comment: good point. I have a try to list them

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Use `runBlocking`, but it will block your function. Your library will have to be able to handle this function being a blocking function. It might be fine, but it will be a problem if the library is calling this function on the main thread.
2. Launch a coroutine from this function, which will run the code asynchronously. The function will return immediately while the coroutine is started asynchronously and will finish some time in the future. This solution is OK if you don't need to wait for the result.

If you launch a coroutine, make sure you use an appropriate CoroutineScope so you don't leak memory. Read the Kotlin coroutines documentation to understand what is the meaning of CoroutineScope. Basically, when a CoroutineScope is cancelled, all its launched coroutines that are still running will also be cancelled. So, when you launch a coroutine, you want to use a scope that will be cancelled at an appropriate time to avoid leaking memory. For example, in an Android Fragment, use the `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` to launch coroutines that capture references to views, and this will prevent those coroutines from leaking views.

Comment: Really thanks your solutions. I use the solution one in my project.
                                                                                               
You mean if a coroutineScope is cancelled, the launched coroutines will be cancelled.
Some values, which may be a var or val, will not be destoried. That will cause the memory link.
----
right?

Comment: Any property that is touched by a coroutine will keep its parent alive. So if you set the text of a TextView in a coroutine, it will prevent the whole Fragment that contains that TextView property from being released in memory until the coroutine finishes or is cancelled.  So using an appropriate scope will prevent that leak from being possible.

Comment: you said "Any property that is touched by a coroutine will keep its parent alive. " -> When I use coroutine in a CoroutineScope, it will keep CoroutineScope alive.
Why is there a memory leak problem here?

Comment: Take an activity for example. If you start a coroutine that does stuff in the activity like manipulating its views, then the activity cannot be released from memory until the coroutine is finished or cancelled. If you cancel the coroutine in the activity’s `onDestroy` then the coroutine is cancelled at the same time as the activity so the activity won’t be leaked. And if you use `lifecycleScope`, this is done for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you use runBlocking, it will block the current thread. However, you can use GlobalScope as below.

```
 overwrite fun doSomething(){
         GlobalScope.launch {
           // code here
        }
     }
```

[runBlocking](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html)
[GlobalScope](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/)